# 2D array won't display correct contents in console grid

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, visual-studio-2013, console, enumerator

I'm working on a simple, text-based Battle Ship game in C++. I'm currently trying to make a grid/board show properly in the console. I had the formatting correct, but I found that the elements of the 2D array wouldn't be right.
Below is an example. **I've set all elements in the 2D grid to *Z*, but they all show up as *Y*, for some reason. Why is it changing the variable?**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

enum Grid {X, Y, Z};

const int GRID_SIZE = 10;
Grid grid[GRID_SIZE][GRID_SIZE] = {Z};

void displayGrid();

int main()
{
    displayGrid();
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}

void displayGrid()
{
    // Display top column of the grid, containing numbers.
    cout << "\t |";
    for (int i = 0; i < GRID_SIZE; i++)
        cout << i << "|";
    cout << endl;

    Grid gridContent;

    for (int y = 0; y < GRID_SIZE; y++)
    {
        cout << "\t" << y << "|";

        for (int x = 0; x < GRID_SIZE; x++)
        {
            gridContent = grid[y][x];
            if (gridContent = X)
                cout << "X|";
            else if (gridContent = Y)
                cout << "Y|";
            else if (gridContent = Z)
                cout << "Z|";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First**:

```
Grid grid[GRID_SIZE][GRID_SIZE] = {Z}
```

initializes only the first element of the array `grid` with `Z` (and the rest of the elements to 0, see [aggregate initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization)). You need a nested loop inside `main` that initializes **all** elements to `Z`, like

```
for(int i = 0; i < GRID_SIZE; ++i)
    for(int j = 0; j < GRID_SIZE; ++j)
        grid[i][j] = Z;
```

**Second**:

```
if (gridContent = X)
```

sets the `gridContent` to `X` (this mistake also occurs in the other `if`s). To test for equality, need to use `==` instead.

**Third**: If you really want to understand why `Y` was displayed before, that's because the condition in

```
if(gridContent = X)
```

evaluates to `false`, since `X` converts to `0`, which is then assigned to `gridContent`. Therefore, the program goes into the other

```
if(gridContent = Y)
```

in which it sets `gridContent` to `Y`, and because the latter is non-zero, the `if` condition evaluates to `true`. You do this in a loop, so you end up displaying all elements as `Y`. Not quite what you wanted.

---

**Best practices**

- One way of avoiding these mistakes is to compile with all warnings on. For example, `g++ -Wall -Wextra test.cpp` spits out

  > warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value [-Wparentheses]
  >
  > ```
  >         if (gridContent = X)
  > ```

  and clang++ is a bit more helpful

  > warning: using the result of an assignment as a condition
  >   without parentheses [-Wparentheses]

  so you definitely know something is wrong.
- Another approach is to always put the [rvalue](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/12/15/understanding-lvalues-and-rvalues-in-c-and-c) on the left of the equality test, like

  ```
  if(X == gridContent)
  ```

  Here `X` is a rvalue, and if by mistake you type `=` instead `==`, then the compiler will issue an error, such as

  > error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment

  since you can not assign to a rvalue.
- Finally, try using standard containers instead of raw arrays, like [`std::vector<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: Such a simple mistake... That's a lot of good information though. Thanks for your time!